# requestloop(loopCondition) doesn't release even after loopCondition is False

Tags: python, pyro

I have some issues with the requestLoop methode of the Pyro4.Daemon object.

What I want is to call remotely a "stop()" method for releasing the requestLoop function and shutdown my daemon.

This small exemple doesn't work

SERVER

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from daemon import Pyro4

class Audit(object):
    def start_audit(self):
        with Pyro4.Daemon() as daemon:
            self_uri = daemon.register(self)
            ns = Pyro4.locateNS()
            ns.register("Audit", self_uri)
            self.running = True
            print("starting")
            daemon.requestLoop(loopCondition=self.still_running)
            print("stopped")
            self.running = None

    def hi(self, string):
        print string

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def still_running(self):
        return self.running

def main():

    # lancement de l'auditor
    auditor = Audit()
    auditor.start_audit()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

CLIENT

```
import Pyro4

def main():

    with  Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:Audit") as au:
        au.hi("hello")
        au.hi("another hi")
        au.stop()
```

What I expect is to see the server print "hello" and "another hi" and then shutdown.

But the shutdown doesn't happen, the server is still blocked in the requestloop method.
I can use my proxy as long as I want.

BUT, if I create another client, at the first remote call, the server will shutdown and the client will throw an error:

```
Pyro4.errors.ConnectionClosedError: receiving: not enough data
```

All my test are saying that I need to create a 2nd proxy and throw the exeption for pass the requestloop on my server.

Does any one have a idea of how to clean this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the `examples/callback/client.py` in the sources you'll see the following comment:

```
# We need to set either a socket communication timeout,
# or use the select based server. Otherwise the daemon requestLoop
# will block indefinitely and is never able to evaluate the loopCondition.
Pyro4.config.COMMTIMEOUT=0.5
```

Hence, you need to do is set the `COMMTIMEOUT` in your server file and it will work fine according to my tests.

Note: You can also add a `print` statement to the `still_running` method to check when it's being called. Without the configuration above, you'll see that it looks like the method is executed only when a new event is received, so the server doesn't shutdown after the next event to the one that set `running` to `False` is received. For example, if you execute the client program twice, the server will shutdown.

Comment: it just work fine. a greate thanks to you.

i have read some doc about the TIMEOUT that say there was a timeout of 3sec for the requestloop. maybe a  old version ?

Comment: note that 0.5 sec for a timeout is very short. il experimented some timeout exception with this value :) 3.5 sec is nice