# Pyro4: Remote object's attributes not changed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyro, pyro4

I'm new to Pyro and pretty new to Python.

I have the following setup: 2 python scripts

Here is server.py:

```
import os
import sys

import Pyro4

class Packet(object):

    must_shutdown = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attr = ""

    def close_connection(self):
        self.must_shutdown=True

def main():
    try:
        daemon = Pyro4.Daemon(host="localhost", port=65432)
        packet = Packet()
        uri = daemon.register(packet, "my.packet")

        print "Ready. Object uri =", uri

        daemon.requestLoop(loopCondition=lambda: not packet.must_shutdown)
        print "after loop"

    except Exception, e:
        print "Exception" + str(e)
    finally:
        print "Finally"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this is client.py:

```
import os
import sys

import Pyro4

def main():
    try:

        packet = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRO:my.packet@localhost:65432")

        packet.some_attr = "this is client"

        packet.close_connection()

        print "client exiting"

    except Exception, e:
        print "Exception: " + str(e)
    finally:
        print "Finnally"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you noticed, in `server.py`, in the `requestloop` there is a **loopCondition** "listening" for **packet.must_shutdown** to change to True. I start `server.py` and then `client.py`. The Pyro Packet object in `client.py` is obtained successfully. 
The problem is that even though I call `close_connection` method on the Pyro Packet object, thus setting `must_shutdown` to "True", the **requestLoop does not break and the server still listening** for requests. I **log in close_connection** and it is called but the interesting thing is that `self.some_attr` **is** still **empty** even thought it was set in `client.py`. It is like, somehow, client deals with another instance of Packet object than the one instantiated in server. What I'm missing here?

Comment: The server.py code won't run as printed above. It has an error where you're creating the packet object. Also, the server object doesn't expose anything, which Pyro4 will print a warning about. Can you please replace the code above with the actual code you're running?

Comment: Indeed I was sending the daemon object as parameter for the Packet. It is no longer the case, edited. As for the '@expose', I use an older version pf Pyro4 which does not function with annotations like '@expose'.

Comment: a Pyro version that doesn't have @expose is ancient and no longer supported. If there are any 'bugs' in this old version they're most likely already fixed in the current release.

Comment: Also, you should at least mention the Pyro4 version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue in this thread which may be considered as duplicate: [requestloop(loopCondition) doesn't release even after loopCondition is False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508112/requestlooploopcondition-doesnt-release-even-after-loopcondition-is-false). The problem was that I didn't set Pyro4.config.COMMTIMEOUT which by default is set to 0 and for some reason it doesn't care to check if requestLoop condition is satisfied or not. This is not specified in the requestLoop docs!

However I met a strange behavior which I consider a bug inside Pyro4.

Comment: Current version of Pyro4 have no problem with this. They frequently check the requestloop condition, whether you use a communication timeout or not. Please upgrade your Pyro4 version before investigating or reporting bugs or problems that have been fixed a long time ago.

Comment: Why do you think that updating is the easy way? Because it's a general solution? Not everyone works on personal projects that can be updated instantly, some of us work on more complex projects on which updating even a third party software cannot be done as you expect. So I feel free to report any bugs/problems on any version as long as I need a fix/workaround on that particular version.

Answer (score -1):

Fixing the issues I mentioned int he comment will probably provide you with the answer.

Most notably;  https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/clientcode.html#accessing-remote-attributes
where it says "you can access **exposed** attributes of your remote objects directly via the proxy."  (emphasis added)

Comment: The issues was just a miss translation from my original code. It should've get me Python errors and not logical communication. However, thanks for the implication.